# In R, test whether coefficients in lm are different each to a given value (other than zero)

Tags: r, regression-coefficients, inference

In R, is there a way to use the `lm` function to test for the hypothesis that the coefficients are different from a value other than zero? For instance, if the model is:

```
Y = a + b1x1 + b2x2 + b3x3 + e
```

It is easy to test whether a single `b` is different from an arbitrary number. If you wanna test for `b1 = 10`, then you can estimate:

```
h0 <- lm(Y ~ offset(10*x1) + x2 + x3)
h1 <- lm(Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
anova(h0,h1)
```

However, what if you want to test at the same time that `a=3`, `b1=10`, `b2=9` and `b3=4` but get the p-values for each? Then an anova would only test whether those restrictions are all true at the same time or not. Is there a way to test such restrictions at once but get the p-values of each coefficient?

Comment: This is primarily about software.  So it is off topic here.

Comment: You could simply fit more models and compare them to `h1`, e.g.:

`h2 <- lm(Y ~ x1 + offset(9*x2) + x3)`

If you want to code it in fewer steps, perhaps, then that question would probably best answered at Stack Overflow.

Comment: The question is originally about software, but I would be more concerned with the multiple comparison problem that arises here - depending on what software approach is used. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rather than using `anova()` to carry out the F test, you can also use `summary()` to get the marginal Wald tests for each coefficient. So it is easy to simply include the entire offset of all terms and then use `summary()`. Here, I use some artificial data with coefficients as suggested in your post:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(
  x1 = runif(100, -1, 1),
  x2 = runif(100, -1, 1),
  x3 = runif(100, -1, 1)
)
d$y <- 3 + 10 * d$x1 + 9 * d$x2 + 4 * d$x3 + rnorm(100)
m <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = d,
  offset = 3 + 10 * x1 + 9 * x2 + 4 * x3)
summary(m)
## Call:
## lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = d, offset = 3 + 10 * x1 + 
##     9 * x2 + 4 * x3)
## 
## Residuals:
##      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
## -3.00507 -0.67884 -0.08825  0.68643  2.55013 
## 
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
## (Intercept)  0.03520    0.10947   0.322    0.748
## x1          -0.09123    0.20091  -0.454    0.651
## x2          -0.19222    0.19572  -0.982    0.329
## x3           0.01885    0.19285   0.098    0.922
## 
## Residual standard error: 1.058 on 96 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.9824, Adjusted R-squared:  0.9818 
## F-statistic:  1784 on 3 and 96 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Another convenient option to conduct these tests of linear hypotheses is the `linearHypothesis()` function from the `car` package. This can replicate both the marginal Wald tests:

```
library("car")
m2 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = d)
linearHypothesis(m2, "(Intercept) = 3")
## Linear hypothesis test
## 
## Hypothesis:
## (Intercept) = 3
## 
## Model 1: restricted model
## Model 2: y ~ x1 + x2 + x3
## 
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
## 1     97 107.67                           
## 2     96 107.55  1   0.11586 0.1034 0.7485
```

...

```
linearHypothesis(m2, "x3 = 4")
## Linear hypothesis test
## 
## Hypothesis:
## x3 = 4
## 
## Model 1: restricted model
## Model 2: y ~ x1 + x2 + x3
## 
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
## 1     97 107.56                           
## 2     96 107.55  1    0.0107 0.0096 0.9224
```

And it can also conduct the F test of all coefficients:

```
linearHypothesis(m2,
  c("(Intercept) = 3", "x1 = 10", "x2 = 9", "x3 = 4"))
## Linear hypothesis test
## 
## Hypothesis:
## (Intercept) = 3
## x1 = 10
## x2 = 9
## x3 = 4
## 
## Model 1: restricted model
## Model 2: y ~ x1 + x2 + x3
## 
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq     F Pr(>F)
## 1    100 108.93                          
## 2     96 107.55  4    1.3802 0.308  0.872
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not clear what your confusion is... but the model

$$Y = X \beta + Z \gamma + \varepsilon$$

Can be equivalently expressed as

$$\left( Y - X\beta^0 \right) = X \left( \beta - \beta^0 \right) + Z\gamma + \varepsilon$$

If we're trying to directly test that $\beta = \beta^0$.

Comment: This approach can be easily accomplished in R via `offset`, setting the offset to $X\beta_0$